# same result from both re.search() and re.match() are the same, but not the same by comparison operator

Tags: python, regex, comparison-operators

here is my code,

```
phone_list = ['234-572-1236 Charles', '234-753-1234 Crystal', '874-237-7532 Meg']

import re
result1 = [re.match(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}', n)   for n in phone_list]
result2 = [re.search(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}', n)  for n in phone_list]

print(result1)
print(result2)

# why they are not the same?
print(result1    == result2)
print(result1[0] == result2[0])
print(result1[1] == result2[1])
print(result1[2] == result2[2])
```

I use re.match() and re.search() to obtain the same result.
but when compare the result by comparison operator, it all gives me False, why?

Comment: `Match` objects could handle same value, but it still different objects. You can obtain unique ID of object with built-in [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), you'll see that ids of objects are different.

Comment: I don't see the outputs from the prints...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Match type does not have a custom `__eq__` method, the equality operation will always return False, unless it's the exact same Match instance.

> The default behavior for equality comparison (== and !=) is based on
> the identity of the objects. Hence, equality comparison of instances
> with the same identity results in equality, and equality comparison of
> instances with different identities results in inequality.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons

Every time you call re.match or re.search, the return value will be a different Match object, even when the input data is exactly the same.

```
>>> needle, haystack = 's', 'spam'                                                                                                                                                                                                  
>>> re.match(needle, haystack) == re.match(needle, haystack)                                                                                                                                                                        
    False
```

Comment: ic, and thank. I always think using `==` is about comparing the value, and `is` is about comparing objects (or id? ). So what you mean is, even the value are the same, but the match type does not have `__eq__`, so this is no longer to compare the value but the object itself, which is about comparing `id`, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

The match type doesn't have a `__eq__` method. So whenever there is no **eq** method the comparison operator compare the memory address of the two objects.

`__eq__`

*This is a magic class method that’s called whenever an instance of this class is compared against another object. If this method is not implemented, then == compares the memory addresses of the two objects by default.*

https://realpython.com/python-is-identity-vs-equality/#how-comparing-by-equality-works

Comment: The re.match method (or maybe function?) *does* have an `__eq__` method. Plus that's irrelevant. It's about the `__eq__` method of its *results*.